# MVVM Light: About extracting the RelayCommand navigation parameter

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, mvvm-light

I'm new to MVVM so I apologize if this is question has a simple answer, but I haven't been able to clear this up through searching Google.

So, basically, I'm using MVVM Light to make a Windows 10 Universal app. Navigation using the method of ViewModelLocator and it works fine. My question is about the accompanying parameter. I have the following method of navigating:

```
public RelayCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs> SelectedItemCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItemCommand
            ?? (_selectedItemCommand = new RelayCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(
                 p => _navigationService.NavigateTo(ViewModelLocator.SecondPageKey, p)));

        }
    }
```

I go to the second page. But how do I extract this **p** on the target page? So far I've figured that

1. This parameter goes into the **OnNavigatedTo** method of the target page's View, which I can then pass to the ViewModel. But that seems kind of not in-line with what MVVM is about. I don't even *have* an **OnNavigatedTo** in my second page and it loads just fine.
2. The other method is to use the *Messenger* method of MVVMLight to get it in the second page's VM, which seems cleaner. But if this is the only right way to do, what's the point of passing a parameter in the RelayCommand at all?

Am I missing some kind of third technique? I'd love to learn something on this. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build and use your own NavigationService. OR improve the current one:

Create BindablePage, which inherit from Page. Inside that:

```
public class BindablePage : Page
{
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        var navigableViewModel = this.DataContext as INavigable;
        if (navigableViewModel != null)
            navigableViewModel.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

        var navigableViewModel = this.DataContext as INavigable;
        if (navigableViewModel != null)
            navigableViewModel.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);

        var navigableViewModel = this.DataContext as INavigable;
        if (navigableViewModel != null)
            navigableViewModel.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
    }

}
```

Create INavigable:

```
public interface INavigable
{
    void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e);
    void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e);
    void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e);
    bool AllowGoBack();
}
```

Implement INavigable in your Viewmodel, and you will handle OnNavigatedTo inside your viewmodel, which have access to p Parameter you sent.